# Crystal Reports image loading on runtime

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, filepath

I have some reports with many records. Those records have images. They were coming from a .NET Dataset object. 
I was initially making the approach of getting the images' contents into the records using System.Byte[] Columns, but the reports took up too much time to load.

I did time profiling. It is not the dataset construction that takes too much.
I put on the table the hypothesis of the images being slowing the process.

So I tried a different approach: Instead of having pictures directly into the tables, I have filepaths. 
Following the practic described in Crystal Reports User Guide, I inserted a OLE object of "Paintbrush Picture Type" and its Image's Graphic Location was ser to a database table field. Additionally I also defined a file hyperlink to be the same field.

I tried, it didn' t show the image. But clicking the hyperlink was OK.

So I added more two OLE object items in the report for testing: the first's Graphic location and hyperlink have the filepath of the first record's image. It is a .jpg file.

I created additionally a .bmp copy of that image and set the second item's filepaths to point to this image.

Tested again, hyperlinks work Ok, but no images shown directly in report .

When I click Preview on Visual Studio 2010 Crystal Reports designer I can see the images, but not in runtime.

So, what am I missing for the images to show?

additional info:
VS 2010 premium

.Net framework 4

Windows 7 64 bits

Crystal reports is integrated on Visual Studio

Thanks in advance,
Sérgio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some frustrating times, it seems I have found a solution in 3 easy steps:

- Uninstall every component of Crystal Reports for VS 2008
- Reopen Visual Studio 2010
- Clean & Rebuild Solution

If you are using CR as a component, during runtime you will notice that the top bar of the component is different: the icons have different design and at right it will say "SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS"